# show element only if it is the only one with with the given class selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a situation where I may or may not have multiple elements with the same class name. I need to show one of them based on some conditions only from css.

Case 1: In below html, if **div** with **only** **info** class is there and is the **only one**, it should always be visible.

Case 2: If there are **two div's** with **only info** class both of them should be **visible**.

case 3: if **one** of them has **extra** class, one with **only info** should be **visible**.

case 4: if there is **only** one div with **both info and extra** classes, it should be **visible**.

is this possible from css..?

> **example:** in below example only second div should be visible

```
<body>
  <div class="info extra">not visible</div>
  <div class="info">visible</div>
</body>
```

I tried to achieve it something like this, but has is not a supported selector in the browsers yet. so is there any other way i can do it?

```
.extra {
    display:none;
}
.info:only-child:has(.browserversionnotice) {
    display:block
}
```

Comment: You can't do this with css

Comment: 'The other way' to do this is by using JS. However, how does this data generate? Maybe you could only load in the data you need to show instead of loading it all but hiding it.

Comment: I don't have option to do it from JS, and to make the situation worst, I need to do it for IE.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly, then this is not possible with CSS alone. You would have to check these conditions in JavaScript when the page loads to hide them if those conditions are met.

Here is one way you could do it:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let elms = document.querySelectorAll(".info");
    if (elms.length == 1) {
       return;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
      if (elms[i].classList.length != 1) {
        elms[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
```

https://codepen.io/CodeBorgg/pen/XWRxqaQ

Answer (score 0):

Your cases can be simplified like below:

- if one div is alone, always visible (whataver the classes)
- if 2 divs then we show only the one not having `.extra` class

```css
.extra {
    display:none;
}
.info:only-child {
    display:block
}

.info:not(.extra) {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="info">visible</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <div class="info extra">visible</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <div class="info extra">not visible</div>
  <div class="info">visible</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <div class="info extra">not visible</div>
  <div class="info extra">not visible</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he means when the innerHTML of the div is empty that "not visible" should be displayed. But if that's what he means by removing the div then that's the correct answer +1